# Need some help with installing steam on my acer chromebook

Tags: steam

When I try to install I get this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

steam:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.3) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: xz-utils:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libtxc-dxtn0:i386

Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: xterm:i386 but it is not going to be installed or

x-terminal-emulator:i386

Recommends: zenity:i386 but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I honestly have no clue what any of this means, and have just copy pasted commands to get to this point. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might mean your Acer chromebook has an ARM CPU, and does not support i386 instructions from Intel. Check with `uname -m` and  `lscpu` commands.

Comment: Got this message from lscpu command: Architecture: aarch64
Byte Order: Little Endian
CPU(s): 4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core: 1
Core(s) per socket: 4
Socket(s):  1
Model: 0
BogoMIPS: 26.00
Flags: fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 cpuid

Comment: It is obviously a good idea to add the output to the question, as it is barely readable when dumped as a comment. Anyway, it is an [aarch64](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm/aarch64) CPU, and Steam and its games are not compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

Steam was primarily concieved as a gaming service for Windows with support for Intel/AMD CPU instruction set.

As the unidentified Aceer chromebook in question has an ARM CPU, there are no 32bit packages in the repositories for aarch64 architecture, including Steam and its dependencies. Because of this, it is not possible to install Steam on that machine.